# Axios: params em GET não funciona - React Native

Tags: node.js, react-native, mongodb, axios

Tenho um banco de dados em mongo com clientes e estabelecimentos.

Quero recuperar os estabelecimentos filtrados por categoria. Meu código está assim:

```
const [datas, setDatas] = useState([]) //recupera os dados
const [category, setCategory] = useState('tecnologias') //recupera a categoria selecionada

async function loadDatas(){
   await api.get('/user/read/establishment', {params:{category: category}})
}
.
.
.
{datas.map(d =>(
    <View style={styles.view}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('Establishment')}>
            < Card title={d.nameEstablishment} time={d.sunday} chave={d._id}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    ))
}
```

em `params:{category:category}` o primeiro category é metadado da tabela estabelecimento do banco de dados e o segundo, é o que eu recebo do React-Native com um toque na tela.

Ele não funciona no app, mas no insomnia sim, por mais que eu tenha visto esse exemplo no site oficial. Estou criando uma gambiarra e fazendo várias rotas, porém fica inviável, porque terá uma hora em que os produtos serão mostrados por categoria e essa não será estática, mas dinâmica (cada estabelecimento com as suas).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 async function loadDatas(){
    const res = await api.get('/user/read/establishment',{ <-- add 
        params:{
            category: "tecnologias" <-- coloca aspas e muda o nome
        }
    })
   setCategory(res.data) <-- add, "res.data" vai depender de como que você está retornando
}
```

seguindo um exemplo como o meu `--->`

```
async function handleTipo(){
    const res = await api.get('/S881TT75a8s5AaAo2iYtR',{
        params:{
            tipo:'Pasta'
        }
    });
    // console.log(res)
    setDocs(res.data.sens)
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta, sua maneira está correta, funciona comigo. O problema é que o meu erro não foi na hora de ler os dados no frontend, mas no meu banco no backend. Ao invés de estar requisitando por 'params', estava requisitando por 'body'.

Comment: kkkk obrigado e boa, conseguiu resolver sozinho.